# passing values between windows with globals

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I'm tryng to send data from Form1 to Form2 using Public variables. I get no errors but the string "another test" does not appear in the text box on Form1. I this the correct way of doing this?

```
' ### Form1 ###
Public Class Form1
    Public MyData As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      MyData = "test"
    End Sub
End Class

' ### Form2 ###
Public Class Form2
    ' Form1
    Private Form1 As New Form1

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      If Form1.MyData = "test" Then
          Form1.Textbox1.text = "another test"
      End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I recommend to use only properties to get/set values in Forms and then display in text boxes from those properties. Better yet is `DataBinding` but if you are not ready yet, try it some other time. Exposing public fields and controls is generally considered a bad idea. There is a reason `.NET` languages have properties.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to set `MyData = "test"` in the constructor of Form1, not the OnLoad event. Even better would be passing the values you want Form2 to know about via it's constructor. This makes it more clear who it's dependents are rather than pulling from static/global state. If it *really* needs to use Form1 then pass the form, if it only needs the string then pass just the string. Always give classes the minimum they need to do their job. This makes them more loosely coupled and easier to test and work with.

---

If form1 is loaded first this would be one way to do it. The reason is it lets you pass the existing form1 into form2 constructor. Otherwise you are creating a new form1 which I don't think is what you want to do

```
Public Class Form2
    Form Form1

    Sub New(ByVal form1 as Form)    
       Form1 = form
    EndSub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
      If Form1.Data = "test" Then
          Form1.Textbox1.text = "another test"
      End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

```
Public Class App
    Sub Main
       Form1 f1 = new Form1();
       // display f1
       Form2 f2 = new Form2(f1);
       // display f2
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @Mr.1.0 Sure, I posted an example.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are creating 2 form1 clases, for example one belongs to yourproject.form1, the second one is yourproject.form2.form1, thats becasue you are creating a new form that belongs to the class form 2.

```
Public Class Form2
' Form1
Private Form1 As New Form1 ' in this line you are creating a new form1 class that belongs to form2

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Form1.MyData = "test" Then
      Form1.Textbox1.text = "another test"
  End If
End Sub
End Class
```

you have 2 options:

1. remove `Private Form1 As New Form1`.
2. change this line Form1.Textbox1 to nameofyourproject.form1 so vb knows exactly wich form 1 you are talking of.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1)  The naming issue mentioned.  If VB isnt confused, I am

2)  You make a new form (New) but never show it.  NEW runs so, you could pass info in the constructor.  Otherwise you need to show the form for the code in Load to execute.

```
Public Class Form1
Public MyData As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
       Handles Me.Load
  MyData = "test"
End Sub
End Class

' ### Form2 ###
Public Class Form2
   ' Form1
    ' really bad naming
    'Private Form1 As New Form1
     Private frm1 As New Form1           ' only a little better

   Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
      Handles Me.Load

       frm1.Show  ' SHOW form1 so the LOAD runs, not just NEW

      If frm1 .MyData = "test" Then
          frm1 .Textbox1.text = "another test"
      End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Bravo for instancing your form, but generally forms ought not mess with other form's controls. THe other way, using the constructor works, but not in this case.  If you wanted Form2 to get some text from Form1 - who created him.    Form1:

```
Dim frm2 As New Form2("some data to pass")
```

In form2:

```
    Public Sub New(txt As String)

    ' NEVER add code before the InitializeComponent call
    ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Label1.Text = txt

End Sub
```

Comment: `New` is a standard proc like the events, you are supposed to pick it off the list and add the one line of code (but it is not on the event list - look on the form procs list).  if you have an older version of VS, it wont handle unmarked line breaks, move the `Handles Me.Load` to the line above (like you see on all the other even handlers).  Note: that method "pushes" data from one form to another, while your OP asked about "getting" data from another form!

Comment: I got it to work also is there a way to do this without having to open an additional form1 window? `frm1.Show`

Comment: "additional"?  is form1 your Startup Form?

Comment: yes then i use a button to call form2 like this `Form2.Show()`

Comment: In that case you CANT use the NEW method because thats what it is meant for - passing important data to a new form.  Actually, your OP code should work just remove `Private Form1 As New Form1` - you were creating a NEW Form1 which was not Shown/Loaded so `MyData` did not get set.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
' ---------
Public Class Form1

    Private innerData As String
    Public Property MyData() As String
        Get
            Return innerData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            innerData = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextData() As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            TextBox1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

' ---------
Public Class Form2

    Private frm1 As New Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)

        If frm1 IsNot Nothing Then
            frm1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        frm1.MyData = "test"
        frm1.TextData = "another test"
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: result]

Comment: this is close to what I want. So I have a button on Form1 that opens Form2. If I use what you have it works, but opens a new Form1 window and now there are two Form1 windows. Is it possible to send "another test" to the original Form1 window that opened Form2?

Comment: On my code only one `Form1` exists, because the statement `Private frm1 As New Form1` only gets called once. I am little unclear on what you are asking. Is `Form1` always visible, or does it get hidden and shown with the button?